# Using copied named ranges in formulas in a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am copying two worksheets from one workbook to a new one using VBA. I am able to copy everything, including the named ranges, over to the new workbook, but the formulas using the ranges do not recognize them unless I manually go into the name manager, double-click on the named range, and select ok.

Is there a way to automate this?

Here is the code for reference:

```
Dim x As Name
Dim NewBook As Workbook

Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add

ShSum.Copy before:=NewBook.Sheets(1)

For Each x In ThisWorkbook.Names
  On Error Resume Next
  ' "x.value" refers to the cell references the defined name points to.
  If Left(x.Value, 14) = "='ACFT Scores'" Then
    NewBook.Names.Add Name:=x.Name, RefersTo:=x.Value
  End If
Next x
```

There are several ranges in other worksheets that I do not need copied over, hence the IF statement.

Comment: Simple Copy paste using the VBA should copy the named ranges as well.
How are you copy pasting the data?

Comment: ShSum.Copy before:=NewBook.Sheets(1)
It does copy the named ranges, but it leaves them linked to the old workbook, instead of using the same references in the new one.